# Trying to set a datetime start time based off datetime.now

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to set my DateTime start variable to change based on what time it is now. my shifts(different start times) are 1: 6am-2pm  2: 2pm-10pm 3: 10pm-6am. I am having trouble writing the if statement to give the correct time.

The short version. I am trying to write C# if statement to figure out which of the the three start it is currently. Below is the code. above is the start times.

The logic I am trying to achieve is to have the DateTime start variable to be set to one of the 3 date time I have listed. Morning, Afternoon, or Evening. The start variable needs to be change values based on DateTime.Now. The View will be refreshing the page every 15 seconds. That will update the DateTime.Now variable.

Thank you for your time.

```
DateTime MORNING;
        DateTime AFTERNOON;
        DateTime EVENING;
        if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 6 || (DateTime.Now.Hour == 6 && DateTime.Now.Minute >= 00))
            MORNING = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 6, 00, 0);
        else
            MORNING = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day, 6, 30, 0);

        if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 14 || (DateTime.Now.Hour == 14 && DateTime.Now.Minute >= 00))
            AFTERNOON = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 14, 00, 0);
        else
            AFTERNOON = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day, 14, 00, 0);

        if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 20 || (DateTime.Now.Hour == 20 && DateTime.Now.Minute >= 00))
            EVENING = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day, 20, 00, 0);
        else
            EVENING = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Year, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Month, DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1).Day, 20, 00, 0);



        DateTime start = ((EVENING > MORNING) ? EVENING : MORNING);
        DateTime end = start.AddHours(8);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Please supply the exact logic you are trying to achieve, it's rather unclear at the moment. Side notes: do *not* concatenate/interpolate SQL values, use proper parameterization instead. You appear to have a design problem as you have a table for each year, and it should be a single table with a year column. Do not cache connection objects. Dispose connection, commmand and reader objects with `using` blocks

Comment: @Charlieface I do realize that table is a huge issue when it changes month or year, however I have no control over that. I am required to build the programs with the tables as shown above.    I have tried to make my quest more clear and removed some code that doesn't help with the issue.

Comment: @Primdonm not really. You could use a VIEW to `UNION ALL` so you only have to query the view. **IF** the tables have `CHECK` constraints on `VDH_Date` that ensure only the correct date is entered, and **IF** `VDH_Date` is used in the query, the server will be able to pick the correct table to query automatically instead of scanning all tables. That's a very early form of hand-crafted partitioning. In all supported versions of SQL Server (2016 and later) you can use table partitioning to achieve the same thing with a single table.

Comment: @Primdonm this works because the server knows about the CHECK constraints and so can eliminate the tables that can't possibly have the filter date. Without the CHECK constraints and `VHD_Date` in the `WHERE` clause, the server would have to scan all tables.

Comment: You still haven't told us what logic you are trying to *achieve*, only what logic you have so far

Comment: @Charlieface Thank you for working with me to try understand what my issues are. I have tried to add my logic, in the hopes that I am becoming more clear. I am sorry for not being clear with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether you need the `MORNING`, `AFTERNOON`, or `EVENING` variables elsewhere in your code, but they are not needed for this; I would remove them from my sample unless you need them in other locations. If you do need those variables, you can replace my `start` sets to new `DateTime` objects with the appropriate variable, but I wanted to demonstrate that the extra variables are not at all required for this. The following should work:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime MORNING = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 6, 0, 0);
DateTime AFTERNOON = MORNING.AddHours(8);
DateTime EVENING = AFTERNOON.AddHours(8);
DateTime start;

// Note that hour 22 is 10PM, not hour 20 as in your example
if (now.Hour >= 22 || now.Hour < 6)
{
    // Evening
    start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 22, 0, 0);
    AFTERNOON -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    MORNING -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}
else if (now.Hour >= 14)
{
    // Afternoon
    start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 14, 0, 0);
    EVENING -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    MORNING -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}
else
{
    // Morning
    start = new DateTime(now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, 6, 0, 0);
    EVENING -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
    AFTERNOON -= TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
}

DateTime end = start.AddHours(8);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help this is what i needed. I looks like I was trying to make it to complicated. You have help save my sanity.